# How do you access the DataContext of a ListViewItem in the style of the ListViewItem?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml, windows-community-toolkit

I have an `ObservableCollection<Foo> fooList`, and the following code for a `MasterDetailsView`, which is just a fancier `ListView`:

```
<controls:MasterDetailsView
            Grid.Row="1"
            x:Name="MasterDetailsViewControl"
            ItemsSource="{x:Bind fooList}"
            SelectedItem="{x:Bind Selected, Mode=OneWay}"
            ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ItemTemplate}"
            DetailsTemplate="{StaticResource DetailsTemplate}"
            NoSelectionContentTemplate="{StaticResource NoSelectionContentTemplate}"
            BorderBrush="Transparent">
    <controls:MasterDetailsView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="Background">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <Binding Path="PathToFooBrushGoesHere" />
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </controls:MasterDetailsView.ItemContainerStyle>
</controls:MasterDetailsView>
```

Each `foo` has an individual property `foo.Brush`, which I want to use to paint the background of the `ListViewItem`. I can't work out what I need to put in `PathToFooBrushGoesHere` in order to get the `ListViewItem` to access the property of `foo` that has the `Brush`.

I had the idea that it might be doable by setting a different `DataContext`, but I couldn't work out how I'd be able to access the `DataContext` of the `ItemTemplate` in the `ListViewItem` style.

How should one go about this styling?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement this effect by binding the `Brush` property to the `ItemTemplate` of `MasterDetailsView`.

Fristly, change the `MasterDetailsView.ItemContainerStyle` as the following to setting the `VerticalContentAlignment` and `HorizontalContentAlignment` properties of `ListViewItem` to `Stretch`,

```
<controls:MasterDetailsView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
    </Style>
</controls:MasterDetailsView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Then bind the `Brush` property to the `ItemTemplate` of `MasterDetailsView`.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ItemTemplate" x:DataType="local:Foo">
    <Grid Background="{x:Bind Brush}">
        <TextBlock Text="ItemTemplate"/>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Hi Breeze, thanks - this is what I've done already to work around this. However, this seems to me more like a workaround than anything else - what if I wanted to set a different property on the ListViewItem? Surely the functionality should be in UWP Community Toolkit to do that?

Comment: @CurtisParfitt-Ford This should be the right way to achieve this effect. You can not bind ListViewItem's property in the style to change the background directly.

Comment: @CurtisParfitt-Ford  Also see the **Migration notes** https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Setter#migration-notes